# How to consume 1000 records of 1 MB each in kafka-consumer-perf-test

Tags: apache-kafka, performance-testing

I am performing kafka load and performance testing.

**Sceanario**:- *To produce and consume 1000 records of 1MB each.*

**Producer command**--
bin\windows\kafka-producer-perf-test.bat --topic Test--throughput -1 --num-records 1000 --record-size 1000000 --producer-props acks=1 bootstrap.servers=localhost:port --producer.config bin\kafka.properties

With above command I am able to produce 1000 records of 1MB each.

EDITED:-

I am using below command for consumer to consume 1000 records of 1MB each:-

bin\windows\kafka-consumer-perf-test --topic Test --timeout 500000 --bootstrap-server localhost:port --messages 1000 --consumer.config bin\kafka.properties

Is this the correct way of consuming 1000 records of 1MB each?

Comment: you can use kafka-console-consumer.bat, and make sure to test with different partitions like 50, 100, 500 etc

Comment: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter
maybe this will help